# How to apply filters of spreadsheet using google apps scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to apply a filter on a spreadsheet and then apply the filter on the active spreadsheet.

Tried using the Filter Class but not sure what is incorrect

```
'''
var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("main sheet");
var dataMatrix1 = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, activeSheet.getLastRow(), activeSheet.getLastColumn());

function applyFilter(){
  Logger.log("mark1");

  var filteredData = dataMatrix1.createFilter(); //filter created
  var a = 'a';
  filteredData.sort(1, false);
  filteredData.setColumnFilterCriteria(1 , a);

  Logger.log("Mark2");
}
'''
```

The spreadsheet has 2 rows with value = 'a' in the first column. Need to apply a filter to the sheet and filter out rows with value = 'a'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close to accomplish your request; you only need to create a [filter criteria](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder.html) instead of using the `a` variable. You can see exactly which methods to use on the following code. Also, the filtered string must be inside of an array, so I sightly modified your `a` variable.

```
function applyFilter() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(
    "main sheet");
  var dataMatrix1 = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, activeSheet.getLastRow(),
    activeSheet.getLastColumn());

  var filteredData = dataMatrix1.createFilter(); //filter created
  var a = ['a'];
  filteredData.sort(1, false);
  var filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(a)
    .build();
  filteredData.setColumnFilterCriteria(1, filterCriteria);
}
```

Please, do not hesitate to ask for more help if you keep having problems.

Comment: Yes this worked and I got the we have to pass it as a list.
But I wish to show the value 'a' and thus used setVisibleValues() but I got this error : "Visible values are not currently supported. As an alternative specify a list of hidden values that excludes the values that should be visible. (line 15, file "Code")"